# Switching between Two Local Planners in Navigation

Tags: ros, navigation, dwa-local-planner, base-local-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I would like to use both `DWAPLanner` and my own local planner on a robot, and depending on the situation switch between these two local planners.

Is it a way in Navigation stack to plug two local planners and switch between them?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/194894/switching-between-two-local-planners-in-navigation/) by [ROSCMBOT](https://answers.ros.org/users/16861/roscmbot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 651 on 2014-10-13

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can do this using dynamic reconfigure. Try running the [gui](http://wiki.ros.org/rqt_reconfigure) client alongside the nav stack to see how the switching works. To do the switching programmatically, you can use the official python [api](http://wiki.ros.org/dynamic_reconfigure/Tutorials/UsingTheDynamicReconfigurePythonClient) or see how people have done it in [c++](http://answers.ros.org/question/12276/is-there-a-c-api-for-a-dynamic-reconfigure-client/) if necessary.

---

Originally posted by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) with karma: 4518 on 2014-10-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ROSCMBOT](https://answers.ros.org/users/16861/roscmbot/) on 2014-10-13**:
Thanks. so I can manually switch the local planners in `gui` client, right? Since I need to do it programmatically, is there a sample code that I can use or have a look?

**Comment by [ROSCMBOT](https://answers.ros.org/users/16861/roscmbot/) on 2014-10-13**:
I just tried the `gui` client, but I couldn't figure out how to plug two local planners at the same time. Currently, in `move_base_params.yaml` I have set `base_local_planner: "dwa_local_planner/DWAPlannerROS"`

**Comment by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) on 2014-10-13**:
You can not "plug" two local planners at the same time, you can switch between one or another using the gui and api that paulbovbel pointed out.

**Comment by [ROSCMBOT](https://answers.ros.org/users/16861/roscmbot/) on 2014-10-13**:
But how can I switch between the two? Currently I can only see `DWAPlanner` in gui, because I have set `base_local_planner: "dwa_local_planner/DWAPlannerROS"`. and if I want to do this switch programmatically, is there a sample code that I can use?

**Comment by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) on 2014-10-14**:
You need to make sure that ROS knows how to locate your custom local planner plugin for it to appear on the GUI (take a look at this: http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/Writing%20A%20Global%20Path%20Planner%20As%20Plugin%20in%20ROS)